# Yocto Build - loadlocale.c #130

Tags: c, linux, gcc, locale, yocto

So I've upgraded to a newer version of Linux kernel using Yocto. The new kernel version is for 4.1.15 and runs on an iMX6 chip. I've also included openssh-server, tools-sdk, and tools-debug for development recipes. The problem is that when I connect to build I get the following error:

> loadlocale.c:130: _nl_intern_locale_data: Assertion `cnt < (sizeof
>   (_nl_value_type_LC_COLLATE) / sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_COLLATE[0]))'
>   failed

Now if I type into the command prompt `sh -c "LANG=en_US"` I get the same error as above. If I type in `sh -c "LANG=/usr/lib/locale/en_US"` then I do not get an error. When I type `locale` everything is listed as POSIX and when I type `locale -a` I get:

- C
- POSIX
- en_GB
- en_US

The last two are stored under `/usr/lib/locale`. My version of gcc is 5.2 and my glibc is v2.22. I've looked all over the internet for other solutions but they are either for Ubuntu where the package manager comes in handy or it's some really specific fix like editing a file that I don't have in my Yocto build.


Edit:
The machine is for a SMARC-FiMX6 SoM and the instructions are [here](http://developer.embedian.com/display/yoctoonsmarc/SMARC-FiMX6-BSP2). I'm not sure what branch of Yocto is being pulled down.

Comment: what machine are you using?  What is the Yocto branch version (Krogoth)?  What are the solutions you found that did not work?

Answer (score 0):

After troubleshooting the problem is from the glibc library. A patch, #114739, is on the openembedded website which details what to do to fix this issue. Just patch the file, rebuild, and the issue is fixed. See [here](http://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/114739/) for details, the patch is at the bottom of the page.